# A kind of average, has it a name?

Tags: terminology, means

Suppose we have an ordered set of numbers, for example:

$\{0,2,3,5,9,10\}$

Now we take the mean of the first two numbers:

$(0+2)/2=1$

And then we take the mean of this number and the third number of our ordered set.

$(1+3)/2=2$

And so on until we did this with the last number of our ordered set.

Has this procedure a name?

Comment: What is your use case for such a mean?

Comment: Notice that the next elements would be
$$
\frac{  \frac{  \frac{0+2}{2}  +3}{2}   +5}{2}
$$
... This doesn't tell the name but it gives insight to the computation process.

Comment: This is a "weighted average".  You can calculate the weights, which are functions of the number of elements and the order of the elements of your list.  For example, with $n=3$, your weights are $\mathbf{w}=\{1/4,1/4,1/2\}$.

Comment: But in the new list, the $i$:th element depends on all $\leq i$ elements of the old list ... So I actually don't think it's a weighted average!

Comment: @lioness99a I really don't know :D

Comment: @SAJW Please add some context about where you found this mean and why you want to use it then

Comment: @MattiP,  given a fixed list size, the weights are predetermined.  This procedure is just an algorithm for calculating the weighted average with the weights specified as shown.

Comment: @MattiP, the weights do not depend on the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually goes by the name "exponential smoothing". Say you have a sequence $\langle a_k \rangle$, you smoothen the sequence selecting $0 \le \alpha \le 1$ and:

$\begin{align*}
A_0
  &= \text{more or less arbitrary value} \\
A_{k + 1}
  &= \alpha a_k + (1 - \alpha) A_k
\end{align*}$

The idea being that the $A_k$ represent a less bumpy representation of $a_k$, incorporating some of the historic evolution. If $\alpha = 0$, only history matters, if $\alpha = 1$ only the last value is considered. Intermediate values give intermediate weight to history.

This is quite popular for example in operating systems, which handle lots of variables that require monitoring, where just the last value can be very misleading, and the resources required to do a decent time series analysis just aren't available (or the analysis warranted). It takes up very little memory (one $A$ value) and negligible processing (if you select $\alpha$ carefully, you don't even need to multiply!).

Answer (score 1):

This is a "weighted average."${}$

Fix $n=$the length of your list, $\mathbf{a} = \{ a_1, \dots a_n \}.$

Then this is $\sum_{k=1}^n w_k a_k.$

$w_1 = w_2 = 2^{n-1},$

$w_k = 2^{n-(k-1)} \, \quad (k\ne 1).$

We can check that the sum of the weights equals one:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n w_k = 2^{n-1} + \sum_{k=2}^{n}  2^{n-(k-1)} = 2^{n-1} + \frac{2^{n-1}-1}{1-2} =1.$$